# Selecting nested third child in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have the following part of HTML and need to extract the **2.56**% value with BeautifulSoup.

```
<div class="box boxRatio">
    <h2 class="sectHed">Dividend Yield Range, Past 5 Years</h2>
    <table class="rangeModTable">
    <tr>
        <td class="col1">Minimum</td>
        <td class="col2">

                1.82%

        </td>
        <td class="col3">Jan 26 2018</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="col1">Maximum</td>
        <td class="col2">

                3.77%

        </td>
        <td class="col3">Oct 08 2019</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="col1">Average</td>
        <td class="col2">

                2.56%

        </td>
        <td class="col3"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

I'm using

```
divyield_box = soup.find(".boxRatio > .col2:nth-of-type(2)")
```

I keep getting AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try SimplifiedDoc's solution.

```
from simplified_scrapy.simplified_doc import SimplifiedDoc
html='''
<div class="box boxRatio">
    <h2 class="sectHed">Dividend Yield Range, Past 5 Years</h2>
    <table class="rangeModTable">
    <tr>
        <td class="col1">Minimum</td>
        <td class="col2">
                1.82%
        </td>
        <td class="col3">Jan 26 2018</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="col1">Maximum</td>
        <td class="col2">
                3.77%
        </td>
        <td class="col3">Oct 08 2019</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="col1">Average</td>
        <td class="col2">
                2.56%
        </td>
        <td class="col3"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</div>
'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
value = doc.select('.box boxRatio').getElementByText('Average').next.text
print (value)
```

Result:

```
2.56%
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS selectors are used with functions `.select()` or `.select_one()`, not `.find()`

You could use:

```
value = soup.select_one(".rangeModTable tr:nth-of-type(3) .col2").get_text(strip=True)
print(value)
```

Prints:

```
2.56%
```

---

Or if you want to select value from row containing text "Average", you could use this:

```
value = soup.select_one('tr:has(td:contains("Average")) .col2').get_text(strip=True)
print(value)
```

Comment: Thanks, but how do I store the value in a variable instead of printing?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "....", line 14, in <module>
    divyield = divyield_box.text.strip()
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: @p3nd0l0 Are you using Python2? I don't know your whole script, but you could try `divyield_box.get_text(strip=True)`